# How to keep the conflict resolutions performed during a git rebase

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Here's our usual workflow:
1. For new feature, we creates a feature branch from master branch
2. We work on the feature branch
3. Before merging the feature branch back to master, we perform rebase against master first, then merge

I assume this workflow is sound. Here is the issue: Sometimes the feature branch runs a long time, so we want to perform rebase periodically so that it doesn't diverge from master too much. The first rebase is fine, we had to do some manual resolution of conflicts, and rebase is done. The trouble begins with 2nd rebase, here we had to redo all the conflict resolutions we already done in the 1st rebase, which is repetitive and error prone. So is there a way we can preserve  the conflict resolution we have done in the 1st rebase?

A crude way of doing this may be this:
1. Create a 2nd feature branch from master at the same time as rebase
2. Merge the rebased 1st feature branch into the 2nd feature branch
3. Continue development on the 2nd feature branch

Is this feasible/advisable? Are there more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Can you please explain why you have to re-do conflict resolutions? When you resolve a conflict in a certain commit, rebased branch contains the commit with resolved conflicts. It does not have a conflict with the master branch, so rebasing again shouldn't cause a conflict, unless master branch has some new conflicting changes.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the command [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) can help here.

As described in [Rerere Your Boat](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html), it records conflicts resolution, and can apply them again.

Make sure to set `git config --global rerere.enabled true` first.